# swiftである時間からできるだけ正確な実行処理方法

Tags: swift

swift4を使ってある時間からの実行処理を行いたいと思っています。

例えば、
05:40:32からあるfunctionを動かしたいと思い、できるだけ正確な時間から起動したいと思っています。

この場合、1秒とか500msごとに05:40:32が過ぎたかどうかチェックして実行処理をすることを考えましたが、できるだけ正確に始めたいと思ったら、この間隔を短くすることしか思いつきませんでした。

もっとスマートなプログラムの仕方はないのでしょうか。
ご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Comment: Swiftはサーバ、mac以外のPCでも動きます。このプログラムのターゲットは何ですか？　一般的には`RunLoop`と`Timer`を使用しますが指定時刻からなるべく早く発火させるだけで精度の保証はないです。それでも何ms毎にチェックするということはSwiftのみだと`RunLoop`を使うことになり、前述の精度を超えることはないと思うのですが、それを知っていてこれ以上の精度を持つ何かを求める質問でしょうか

Comment: 違う端末同士でつなぎ合わせると大きな動く絵になるということをさせたく、タイミングをあわせたいと思った次第です。時間で合わせるのは限界がありそうですね。

Comment: そういう場合、端末同士がそれぞれの端末時間で発火時刻を指定しても信頼できません。全員が同じタイムサーバに合わせていないかもしれないし、タイムサーバを使っていないかもしれません。ある端末をホストにし（スマートフォンなどに限りません）、他の端末へリアルタイムで更新を指示するのがいいのではないでしょうか。この場合、時刻合わせよりも、多くの端末へラグなしに更新命令をプッシュする方法が課題になります。

Comment: これってどういった環境で実行するのか分からないのですが、手動で同期を調整させる仕組みを作って処理させてはどうでしょうか？（例えば線を反復させてそれを目視で合わせさせて処理の基準とさせて見たりとか…）同期させるとすると同時に接続する台数とか、それぞれの端末のスペックが統一されているのかだとか、実際の実行時の処理の負荷はどうだとか、条件によっても時間経過とともにズレたりしそうな気もしますが…

Comment: 手動でもどうしてもズレますかね。ズレない方法模索してみます。

Comment: ズレないとは「 **許容できる誤差** の範囲におさまる」ということですよね？　通信経路などによるロスがある限り本当の意味の「ズレない」はありえないです。NTPもそのために遅延をできる限り補正します。まず、「できるだけ正確な」ではなく、その動かす絵の全体の整合性が保てる「◯◯ミリ秒までの誤差」を前提に実用的な同期方法をたずねてはどうでしょうか